# How to only show days, not hours, on the calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I set up my Google calendar to only have one box for one day, and not a box for every hour of the day?  Just "hiding morning and night" is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: And am I right in assuming month-view is not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to change to the "Month" view. That view shows a day in one box.

[image]